# How to write remote/local server file manipulation methods more efficiently in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I am trying to write a method which will perform some file manipulations on the files existing on a server. For example: copy from source to destination, symlink a file, read a file, etc. Here I need to handle 2-scenarios i.e., server can be local or remote.

In remote server scenario, I am connecting to the server (using net/ssh) and then running shell commands using `exec` method. And for local server, since I do not need to establish any connections I am using Ruby `FileUtils` methods. I have pasted the piece of code for your reference.

I wanted to check if someone can suggest me to write this method more efficiently.

```
def create_link
 begin
   if self.particular_file_exists?
     if !@ssh.local
       @ssh.exec!("ln -s file1 file1-dump")
     else
       FileUtils.ln_sf("file1", "file1-dump")
    end
  end
  rescue => e
    $LOG.log(2, "Error occurred")
  end
end
```

Comment: What about this code makes it seem inefficient to you?  Have you profiled it?

Comment: Try to avoid double-negative conditions. Here the `else` evaluates *if-not-not-ssh is local*. Just flip the two lines around, remove the negative, and it's a lot cleaner. It's worth paying attention to this before you have code like `unless !@ssh.not_remote?` and you can't even figure out what it means.

Comment: This is also a case where having a standard interface implemented by two different handler classes would make it easy to switch out entire behaviours.  Use subclasses, not `if` statements when you've got two different approaches to solving the same problem.

Comment: One more thing: Arguments to commands like `ln` **must** be escaped with something like [`shellescape`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/shellwords/rdoc/Shellwords.html#method-c-shellescape) or this code will malfunction in a huge way with filenames that have spaces in them, or possibly expose you to severe security holes due to how the shell interprets these commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just quick edit:

```
def create_link
  return unless self.particular_file_exists?
  if @ssh.local
    FileUtils.ln_sf "file1", "file1-dump"
  else
    @ssh.exec! "ln -s file1 file1-dump"
  end
rescue
  $LOG.warn "Error occurred"
end
```

For deeper ideas you should ask https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

I can't say about performance optimizations, but here's what I think is a more maintainable/extensible code. You don't need all those local/remote branches in every goddamned method. Instead, extract environment specific behaviour into their own objects and delegate work to them. Something like this:

```
class FileManipulator
  attr_reader :handler

  def initialize(ssh)
    @handler = ssh? RemoteHandler.new(ssh) : LocalHandler.new
  end

  def create_link
    handler.create_link if handler.particular_file_exists?
  rescue => e
    $LOG.log(2, "Error occurred")
  end

  RemoteHandler = Struct.new(:ssh) do
    def create_link
      ssh.exec!("ln -s file1 file1-dump")
    end
  end

  LocalHandler = Struct.new do
    def create_link
      FileUtils.ln_sf("file1", "file1-dump")
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: When it was done using `if`, two branches were only 1 line apart. Now they are 5 lines apart and the distance can even increase. This approach never never making the code more readable.

Comment: @Nakilon: Imagine 5 types of handlers and each method is 3-10 lines long. Keeping all those implementations together, like in the question, is a huuuuge violation of SRP. You'll get lost in the woods in no time.

Comment: Imagine 10 methods instead of 5. With total of at least 25% more lines of code, which are mostly a syntax boilerplate such as `def`, `do`, `end`.

Comment: Amount of LOC has no correlation with readability of the code.

Comment: Amount of LOC has a strict correlation with amount of bugs.

Comment: @Nakilon I disagree. You can write super-terse one-liners (think email-RFC-grade regexes or something), in which bugs or even their actual purpose is very much not obvious.

Comment: This might be better expressed as either a handler class with subclasses for each behaviour (local/remote) or a single class where instances of it mix-in one of two modules depending on what type it is.

Comment: @tadman: yeah, many options here, but the core idea is the same: delegate, don't branch. We can do error handling in the base class of the handler. In this case, the only responsibility (as in SRP) of the manipulator would be selecting the handler. :)

Comment: @tadman: I heard that runtime mixing of modules is super bad for optimization. This is the main beef jruby guys had with refinements and DCI.

Comment: "You can write super-terse one-liners..." -- this has no logic. "You can fall from the roof even without standing on the edge, so don't tell me not to stand there". Same logicless demagogy.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Mixins can be trouble, but it's just one of the possible solutions here. Lightly called code isn't as performance sensitive as something that's more aggressively utilized. A handful of SSH calls is not going to cripple your program and the maintainability benefit might be worth it. Judgement call.